# MS Access Newbie Trying to fill data based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm attempting to create a table that is basically a company intranet staff directory and I have 6 office locations. 1 of the fields is the office phone number. I can't figure out how to copy the ph number across every row I want it in so I wondered if it was possible to have it auto fill based on the postcode field??

Basically if the postcode is 6000 then the next field should be 9222-0000. For post code 6100 the number is 9222-1111.

Honestly to go one step further both the postcode field and the phone number field could auto fill from the suburb field. If I could type it once then any entry that had the suburb would get that postcode and that phone number.

Win 10\MS Access 2016 and almost no experience using Access if that wasn't already apparent.

Comment: Are you entering the data into your tables through an MS Access form?

Comment: No, directly into the table.